# Dependent observeEvents cause problems in complex applications

Tags: r, shiny

I prepared rather simple shiny application which resembles the problem in my much more complex application.

The three necessary components of my application are:

- The number, i.e. year, can be changed in two different ways: by 1) adding a value in the textInput or 2) by clicking the action button
- When the year is changed by the actionButtion, it must automatically change current value in the textInput box
- When the year is changed by the textInput, reactive value for the
  action button must reset to zero.

I have two `observeEvents` which both target two reactive values. The problem is, if I click the `actionButton` several times too quickly, this creates a loop of switching between those two events.
Is there any efficient tool available in Shiny which help in such situations? E.g. to prevent users to click on the button prior the execution of task.

```
# import libraries
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("ui_year"),
      uiOutput("ui_plus")
    ), 

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1")
    )

)))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Generate random data
  data <- data.frame(
    year = seq(1900, 2000),
    value = runif(n = 101, min = -3, max = 3)
  )

  # Define two reactive values: add and year
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  rv$add <- 0
  rv$year <- 2000

  # render actionButton
  output$ui_plus <- renderUI({
                 actionButton(inputId = "add",
                          label = paste0(""),
                          icon = icon("plus"))
    })

  # render textInput
  output$ui_year <- renderUI({
             textInput(inputId = "year_1", label = NULL, 
                       value = eval(parse( text = rv$year)),
                       width = "100%",
                       placeholder = NULL)
    })

  # Define two observe events, based on A) action button and B) textInput
  observeEvent(input$year_1, {
    rv$year <- input$year_1
    rv$add <- 0
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    rv$add <- rv$add + 1
    rv$year <- as.numeric(rv$year) + 1
  })

  # Render output
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

     sumValue <- as.numeric(rv$year)  + as.numeric(rv$add)

  ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = value)) + geom_line()+ annotate("text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = -0.2, vjust = 1, label = sumValue )

  })

  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The issue does not seem to occur if in the `observeEvent(input$add` you replace `rv$year <- as.numeric(rv$year) + 1` with `updateTextInput(session, "year_1", value = as.numeric(rv$year) + 1)`and if in the `textInput` you replace `value = eval(......)` with `value = "2000"`. However I'm not sure this solves the problem in your real app; this toy example looks superficial, we don't understand why you use this machinery here.

Comment: I could potentially provide less superficial example, but I believe if we solve the issue in the provided example, this should serve also as a solution to my application. I will implement your suggestion and come back with the fedback asap.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Your suggestion goes in the right direction, but there is one problem: reactive value rv$year is not getting updated. updateTextInput updates only text input and not the reactive value. I have updated my question with necessary components, so it should be clearer the desired behaviour my application.

Comment: this worked for me. `updateTextInput` updates `input$year_1`, and then you have an observer of `input$year_1` which stores the value of `input$year_1` in `rv$year`.

Comment: You saved the day! This works also in my original application.